# select default option in dropdown dependent in ANGULAR.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dependent dropdown I select a country. I need to be marked by default "manizales" if Colombia is selected and "Chicago" is marked if United States is selected (USA). I have tried many things, but do not know how to mark the first time a default option.

```
<select id="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country  in countries track by country.id">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>Departement:
<select id="state" 
ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.id as state.dep for state in ((countries | filter:{'id':selectedCountry})[0].states) track by state.id">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

maybe I did not understand me. I need a country when the first dropdown is loaded appears, for example Colombia, and that once this marked by "manizales" defect

http://plnkr.co/edit/6gvGmfqIqEAyYtYyYIb8?p=preview

Comment: I changed some things and it works now: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IhLYh2RkhGxdOKQzWX2T?p=preview).

Comment: @user6188402 maybe I did not understand me. I need a country when the first dropdown is loaded appears, for example Colombia, and that once this marked by "manizales" defect

Comment: Look my plunker again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the following changes using `ng-change`. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/RUxVch?p=preview

```
<select id="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country  in countries" ng-change='selectedState = selectedCountry.states[0].id;'>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>Departement:
<select id="state" 
ng-model="selectedState" 
ng-options="state.id as state.dep for state in selectedCountry.states">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Comment: maybe I did not understand me. I need a country when the first dropdown is loaded appears, for example Colombia, and that once this marked by "manizales" defect.

Comment: Oh ok, add `$scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[0]; $scope.selectedState = $scope.selectedCountry.states[0].id;` after you declare the `$scope.countries` array

Comment: if I do, "Manizales" is not selected

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `ng-change` on the country input and assign the `$scope.selectedState` when that changes. I would also recommend adding a `defaultStateId` property to each country to make this more flexible.

So your country HTML would become:

```
<select id="country" ng-change="CountrySelected()" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.id as country.name for country  in countries track by country.id">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

And your `CountrySelected` function would look something like this:

```
$scope.CountrySelected = function() {
    var countryId = $scope.selectedCountry;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.countries.length; ++i) {
        var country = $scope.countries[i];
        if (country.id === countryId) {
            $scope.selectedState = country.defaultStateId;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: maybe I did not understand me. I need a country when the first dropdown is loaded appears, for example Colombia, and that once this marked by "manizales" defect.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add an 'defaultIndex': 0 foreach father element, [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IhLYh2RkhGxdOKQzWX2T?p=preview)

var Aplic = angular.module("Aplic", []);

Aplic.controller('CountryCntrl', function($scope) {

```
$scope.countries = [{
    'id': '1',
    'name': "Colombia",
    'defaultIndex': 0,
    'states': [{
        'id': '12',
        'dep': "Manizales"
    }, {
        'id': '11',
        'dep': "Bogota"
    }]
}, {
    'id': '2',
    'name': "USA",
    'defaultIndex': 1,
    'states': [{
        'id': '3',
        'dep': "California"
    }, {
        'id': '15',
        'dep': "Chicago"
    }]
}];

$scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[0];
```

});

Answer (score 0):

replace 
ng-model="selectedState"

with below code 
ng-model="(countries | filter:{'id':selectedCountry})[0].states[0]"

Comment: it is working if i kept //$scope.selectedCountry='1'; in js.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you need to do:

1) add an `ng-change` to the `selectedCountry` dropdown that will set the `selectedState` model to the first state in your list

2) re-arrange the states in your json so that the default state is the first one.

[Here is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NAkLI9eZL1wshtoUmSFN?p=preview)

You could also extend it to add a default value to either the country list or a default boolean to the state object.